# Where are the stages in IEEE 754 32-bit floats?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

I know IEEE 754 floats lose precision as they go, but it's not exactly gradual. Because of exponent math, it essentially shifts the decimal over whenever it's reached a maximum. However, since this isn't in base 10, I know it doesn't go from, say, 10.000 to 100.00. Still, from how I understand it, it does something similar in base 2. I'm guessing there are a lot of these shifts between 0 and 1, but they become very spaced out above that. **Where do these shifts in precision occur?** This could be useful for telling users when my program might start losing precision.

Comment: Why 32 bit float, rather than 64 bit, if precision matters enough to track the steps?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Because memory matters more, here, but good point!

Answer (score 2):

For non-denormalized, non-zero, finite floating point numbers (i.e. most "normal" floating point numbers), the mantissa in IEEE 754 is in the range [1.0, 2.0). The mantissa is written without its leading 1.

Thus, quite simply, bits of precision will be lost every time an operation would force the mantissa out of this range (requiring the exponent to be adjusted, and the mantissa to be shifted).

How the precision is lost will depend heavily on the operations you perform.  For example, if you perform naive summation over a wide range of values (rather than, say, Kahan summation), you will lose precision much faster than you need to.

Answer (score 2):

These shifts occur at powers of 2. Since binary32 floats are composed of a 24-bit number in the interval [1, 2) multiplied by a power of 2, they can store at most the first 24 bits of the binary representation of a number. Anything in the interval [1, 2) has precision down to increments of 2^-23. Anything in the interval [2, 4) has precision in increments of 2^-22. Anything in the interval [0.5, 1) has precision in increments of 2^-24.

In general, if we have

```
2^n <= x < 2^(n+1)
```

and x is within the normal range, then x is represented by the nearest multiple of `2^(n-23)`.

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm still not able to wrap my head around it. You're saying it's like this? http://wolfr.am/1iqTcCJ What's that mean?

Comment: @Supuhstar: The graph you've produced isn't anything useful. I'm saying that if `2^n` is the highest power of 2 that's <= x (where n may be negative), then x is represented with precision in increments of `2^(n-23)`.